# How to get an AWS RDS DbInstance Resource ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am trying to come up with options for the retrieval of an AWS RDS DbInstance Resource ID during the deployment of a stack using the AWS CDK.

The Resource ID is needed in order for a lambda to use IAM authentication with the RDS instance - [see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html)

It appears that even CF is unable to return the Resource ID value using ref or getAtt functions - [see here](https://theburningmonk.com/cloudformation-ref-and-getatt-cheatsheet/)

Running `cdk deploy` deploys the entire app, including the rds database instance and the lambdas, so how can the resource ID be provided to the Lambda policy for IAM authentication?

I'm interested if anyone has solved this issue OR what workarounds have been used. Does the deployment need to be done in multiple stages with separate CDK deploy commands or apps?

All help much appreciated,

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requierements right that the following CDK code should get your Lambda function `rds-db:connect` permissions.

```js
let vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'vpc')
let db = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'db',{
     vpc: vpc,
     engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.mysql({version: rds.MysqlEngineVersion.VER_8_0})
})
let func = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda',{
     vpc: vpc,
     code: lambda.Code.fromInline(`exports.handler = function(event, ctx, cb) {return cb(null, \"hi\"); }`),
     runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
     handler: "index.handler"
})
db.grantConnect(func)
```

Comment: Hey @Pistazie thanks so much for your answer. I read it with much excitement BUT then found that this function doesn't appear to work (as expected). And it is for the same fundamental issue with CloudFormation: in that it doesn't expose the resource ID for RDS db instances. See here - https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/aws/aws-cdk/11851/803200233

Comment: Hey @SamBrick, what I do in production (with DBCluster and a serverless MySQL DB) is to let cdk create a secret attachment for the DB. the created secret is then a JSON which contains the host, user, password and more. 

I then fetch this secret when my app bootstraps (Spring-boot in a fargate container) and configure my connection.

This is documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-rds-readme.html#starting-a-clustered-database

In also allow security group access from the fargate containers to the dbCluster. 

I never really did that with Lambdas.

Comment: Another idea: maybe use RDS Proxy, it's supposed to play very well with lambdas and RDS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Pistazie - I think we are going to separate out the CDK app into two apps - one for the db and one for the lambdas. Once the db app has deployed we'll then query the resource ID using the CLI via Jenkins and provide that to the lambda app when it deploys.